# Are there actual levels in Tiger! Tiger! aside of first one?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I've managed to beat level 1 of Tiger! Tiger! minigame several times. getting some equipment for Poppi. Yet, game doesn't allow me to continue to level 2, and just ends. So, my actual question is - are there more levels? If so, are there any conditions to unlock them (if it is plot-related - please, don't spoil it, just say "it's plot-related")?

Comment: I don't play the game, but I'm fairly sure there must be more levels, otherwise they wouldn't call it "level 1".

Comment: It’s worth noting that the high score screen displays the top scores for levels 1 through 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

Once you continue in the main story, new levels will open up.

- > Level 2 will open up when you enter Uraya.
- > Level 3 will open up when you enter Mor Ardain
- > Level 4 will open up when you enter Tantal
- > Level 5 will open up when you enter the World Tree

Comment: Could you please cover specific entries for level with spoiler tags? It really looks like, you know, actual spoilers.

Comment: @lentinant I can see level 5 being a spoiler, but really, exploring continents in an RPG game - what did you expect?